# Newbie - Sharepoint 2007 - change forms from dropdown list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a situation where I require users to view a different depending on the information they wish to submit. I would like to have the following dropdown

Type of submission
    Type A
    Type B

Depending on the selection, the user is then presented with the corresponding submissions form. Is this at all possible?

Thanks,
CL

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Do I understand you correctly that you want to have a dropdown list and depending on its choice you want to call a different form (of type A or B)?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible if you use content types. Each content type may use a subset of list fields and also each content type can be bound a different new/edit form.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms472236.aspx) for more detailed reference.

Comment: Totally agree, use content types to differentiate between kinds of documents / (InfoPath) forms.